# Optimization with autograd

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, gradient-descent, autograd

I have a continuous-valued dataset {input, target}. The input (x) dimension is 224 and the target (y) dimension is 1. Values of y range between (0,1). There are only around 1000 data points. My objective is to maximize the function, y = f(x) (assuming it exists) i.e., find a value of x (this x may not be present in the given dataset) to produce a y closer to 1.
What is the best method to do this?

My idea was to first train a neural network to fit the data. Then use the autograd feature to get df/dx at the input, to guide a gradient descent path for x i.e., using the neural network as the black box which could also generate gradient. The error at the output would be (1-y). I'm lacking the necessary keywords to search for a solution of this fashion. Is this a feasible approach? What are the other available methods?

Comment: Try to approximate the function and verify if it is convex unless a descent gradient algorithm may not converge

Comment: @Jad The function is not available. Only the dataset is available. What is the approach here?

Comment: Try to fit it by trying the different method of curve fitting like polynomial interpolation or regression.